# While installing anything: Clearsigned file isn't valid

Tags: 14.04

Whenever  I try to install something (including Spotify) I get the same error:

```
E: GPG error: http://repository.spotify.com trusty InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is actually appears to be an issue with Spotify's repository. Per following thread there is a DNS redirect that is breaking things.

http://community.spotify.com/t5/Help-Desktop-Linux-Mac-and/Spotify-0-9-11-for-GNU-Linux/m-p/844713

There is a temp fix describe in the thread that has worked for several people (myself included):

In terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r "deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free"
sudo add-apt-repository "deb  http://repository-origin.spotify.com stable non-free"
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: I got this error now: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7748151/

Answer (score 0):

The link in your /etc/apt/sources.list does not seem to be what the people at spotify are recommending.  The following is from https://www.spotify.com/us/download/previews/.

Open a terminal window by typing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> then type

`gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`

Find the line which looks like

`http://repository.spotify.com trusty InRelease`

Delete the whole line

Now add the line

```
deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
```

Exit and save the changes to /etc/apt/sources.list

In the terminal (which is still open) enter the commands

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 94558F59
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install spotify-client
```

Note that this is a 'linux preview' version of spotify and may not be entirely stable.  Spotify also suggests that you might try spotify for wine.

Comment: so what am I supposed to do?

Comment: @user158049  I'll modify my prior answer